# MonoDevelop can't find AVD or it dont get noticed it is running

Tags: android, monodevelop, xamarin.android, android-virtual-device

Im new in Mono and Android. I've looked for this problem and the most near I found talks about a Java bug and says to "reinstall" the SDK, witch I did resulting no success.

What I notice is that Android Virtual Device Manager has a list of all my devices at some folder, but try to initiate the device in another folder.

You can see those two locations (in my machine) here:
[image: http://yfrog.com/nydnrp]

If I copy the avd folder to the location where it try to start the emulator, it starts but MonoDevelop dont get noticed. The emulator never is available in the "Select device" popup window and the "Ok" button is never available. I've looked if I can find some place to configurate the correct path to the AVD or some way to tell MonoDevelop that the emulator is ruuning but with no success.

Someone can help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

. I get it.
After spending 3 days looking around, I found the problem in a Google forum: there is a bug with the AndroidSDK on Windows 7 x64. The solution is: you need to create an "environment varialble" to tell AVD Manager (and all AndroidSDK) where is the "root" folder of your SDK installation. Crazy, an?

Well, to do that (if you don't know yet), do this:

1. Right click on "Computer" and choose "properties".

After that:

1. Click on "Advanced system settings"
2. At "Advance" tab, click on "Environment Variables..."
3. Click on "New..." Button
4. Insert "ANDROID_SDK_HOME" as the "Variable Name" and the folder where your AndroidSDK is located/installed. In my case it is something "D:\MY_COMPANY\ANDROID\MONO_INSTALL\ANDROID_SDK\android-sdk" where "android-sdk" is the root folder of my SDK installation. Insert all these values without "quotes" of course.
5. Click OK button as many times you need to close all Windows.
6. Restart your AVD Manager and MonoTouch.

Everything should works fine now. But... still having a problem: When MonoDevelop runs the application, on "Select Device" window it can't see any AVD to Start. I'm starting the AVD emulator from AVDManager and wait it loads completely. When it is full started, I hit "refresh" button on MonoDevelop "Select Device" and wait the emulator appears on the list. I can't select that and hit "OK" button, but a "double click" in the name of the emulator do the trick. MonoDevelop "understand" that I want to use the emulator and start build and deploy the application.

I really hope it help guys who is startting learning MonoDevelop and Android. This kind of "buggy" and "environment configuration cheats" should be more well documented by the Xamarin developers. These kind of "SDK bugs" is not MonoDevelop team fault, of course, but warning its potential clients would help and brings confidence on their side.

Comment: MonoDevelop only detects AVDs started from MonoDevelop or Visual Studio, because that way it can validate that they were started with several necessary options.